# Scrollbar is not showing up in dropdown in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am facing a weird problem. I have a div like the following.

```
<div class="dropdown3 dropdown-style" style="overflow-y:scroll">
   <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li>1k</li>
    <li>5k</li>
    <li>10k</li>
    <li>25k</li>    
    <li>35k</li>                               
  </ul>
</div>
```

My css is like this:

```
.dropdown3 {
  position: absolute;   
  top: 30px;  
  background: #fff;  
  left: -15px;  
  z-index: 1;  
  display: none; 
  height:85px;
  max-height:85px;
  overflow:scroll; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;  
   border-radius: 5px;    
}
```

Though it is working in firefox, for some reason it is not working in chrome!  Chrome automatically puts style="overflow: hidden;"         whereas I explicitly mentioned it to scroll in the div.

Comment: `overlow:scroll;` should it not be : `overflow:scroll;`

Comment: sorry typo in typing the question. Nope it does not work.

Comment: how can you see the element with `display: none;`?

Comment: I display it dynamically via jquery using class name

Comment: try `overflow:scroll !important;`

Comment: uuhuuu...works man! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `overflow:scroll !important;`

Comment: allows css to override all other methods of changing the style, maybe this helps explain :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css